# Manipulating Values in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to be able to decrease a value in an ArrayList to simulate an object being removed from a pile. However I cannot do this with ArrayList(String)

The example below is what i've attempted.

```
ItemArray.get(pressedItem + 1) = (ItemArray.get(pressedItem + 1)) - 1
```

Is there a way to get values in an ArrayList into a more manipulatable state?

EDIT:

Just to point out that my ArrayList is ArrayList(String) at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`List#set()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) to mutate the list.

```
List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// later...
int position = pressedItem + 1;
items.set(position, items.get(position) - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response man but `ItemArray.get(position) - 1` returns an error `The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int`

Comment: @Jack That means your list is set to contain Strings. Java is strongly typed, it's not gonna magically turn a String into a numeric value. Either specify your list as containing the Integer type or [convert the String to an Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Ah brilliant, that's perfect thank you =) Could you put something about converting to an integer in your answer? Thank you.

Comment: Use the right data type for your data; store a list of integers, not strings.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is a class. Assuming `ItemArray` is an instance of that class (please start variables with a lower-case letter, btw), you'll need to use it through method calls. In your case, `set`. Like so:

```
itemArray.set(pressedItem + 1, itemArray.get(pressedItem + 1) - 1)
```

Mind that the above will only work exactly like that if you declared your `ArrayList` as containing Integers or some other numeric type, so Java can do the conversion stuff for you:

```
List<Integer> itemArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Doesn't look like I can declare my ArrayList with <Integer> because i'm populating it with the contents of a CSV file :/ It is currently <String>

Comment: @Jack Then you'll either have to a) convert while populating the list or b) store Strings and convert when they're used. a) is preferrable since it catches incorrect input sooner and makes later processing easier.